# What is the frequency that the developer history tag's percentage score is updated?

Tags: support, questions

I know that some scores takes time to be updated and I would like to know when the percentage of the tag is updated?

I'm not sure if I'm clear on what is updated, so here is an image

[image]

In what frequency, this percentage is updated?

Comment: The tag score jobs runs every 48 hours, if I recall correctly.